# Pig Split Line on Regex

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm attempting to write a PIG script that reads in a large single line file and splits it into a large multiple line file. I'm attempting to split the text when I find the string "alert" or "none";

My script is:

```
data = LOAD '/myfile' USING TextLoader() as (line:chararray);
data_split = FOREACH data GENERATE FLATTEN (STRSPLIT(line, '/none|alert/')) as line:chararray);
```

In order to validate I have split this correctly I am generating a count by using:

```
x = GROUP data_split by line; 
count = foreach x GENERATE COUNT(data_split);
dump count;
```

This always returns 1, which is probably because i'm not splitting this correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex syntax is incorrect, if you are attempting to do what I think you are.

Pig uses standard Java regular expression syntax.  Check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

I believe you are looking for `STRSPLIT(line, '(none|alert)')`.

In addition, the rest of your script doesn't do what you want.  `STRSPLIT` returns a tuple, and when you `FLATTEN` a tuple, it doesn't distribute the fields to multiple rows, as happens when you `FLATTEN` a bag.  Instead, you end up getting multiple fields, and you happen to be naming the first one of those `line`.

Unless you know ahead of time the number of fields in your tuple you will wind up with (in which case, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594144/flatten-tuple-like-a-bag)), or unless your resulting strings do not contain any characters like space, comma, and so on (in which case, you can use [this method](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pig-user/201105.mbox/%3CBANLkTi=PicbP=UZx=Z7Vurb6DkMbV2cETA@mail.gmail.com%3E)), your best bet is probably to write a custom UDF to replace `TextLoader()` whose input record separator is your special sequence of characters.

Comment: So now I get the following error. Can I still get a count from this? Invalid field projection. Projected field [line] does not exist in schema: group:chararray,data_split:bag{:tuple(line:chararray)}.

Comment: I don't see how you could have gotten that error from the script you posted.  In any case, there's a fatal flaw in your approach; I've updated my answer to reflect that.